# How do you pipe input through grep to another utility?

Tags: bash, cygwin, grep, pipe, cut

I am using 'tail -f' to follow a log file as it's updated; next I pipe the output of that to grep to show only the lines containing a search term ("org.springframework" in this case); finally I'd like to make is piping the output from grep to a third command, 'cut':

```
tail -f logfile | grep org.springframework | cut -c 25-
```

The cut command would remove the first 25 characters of each line for me **if it could get the input from grep!** (It works as expected if I eliminate 'grep' from the chain.)

I'm using cygwin with bash.

Actual results: When I add the second pipe to connect to the 'cut' command, the result is that it hangs, as if it's waiting for input (in case you were wondering).

Comment: If I stop after grep (without the pipe to 'cut'), it works (without stripping the first 24 or 25 chars).

Comment: The real problem here, is that `tail -f` never finishes, so the rest of the pipeline keeps waiting for more input

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On my system, about 8K was buffered before I got any output. This sequence worked to follow the file immediately:

```
tail -f logfile | while read line ; do echo "$line"| grep 'org.springframework'|cut -c 25- ; done
```

Answer (score 30):

Assuming GNU grep, add `--line-buffered` to your command line, eg.

```
tail -f logfile | grep --line-buffered org.springframework | cut -c 25-
```

**Edit:**

I see grep buffering isn't the only problem here, as cut doesn't allow linewise buffering.

you might want to try replacing it with something you can control, such as sed:

```
tail -f logfile | sed -u -n -e '/org\.springframework/ s/\(.\{0,25\}\).*$/\1/p'
```

or awk

```
tail -f logfile | awk '/org\.springframework/ {print substr($0, 0, 25);fflush("")}'
```

Comment: --line-buffered didn't work for me - that buffers the *output* of grep. If you do tail -f logfile|cut -c 25- it still just sits there. The buffering is being done on the output of tail.

Comment: Revised, seems like you're being bitten by stdout buffering in cut, these should work for you

Comment: Thank you! this is really useful when pipe-chaining multiple greps. e.g. someprogwithoutput | grep --line-buffered filterpattern | grep --color highlightpattern

Comment: Is that `fflush` a typo?

Comment: @thecoshman: I wrote this a while ago, but I don't think it's a typo. It's a forced output flush. the `""` argument is gawk specific though.

Answer (score -1):

What you have should work fine -- that's the whole idea of pipelines.  The only problem I see is that, in the version of `cut` I have (GNU coreutiles 6.10), you should use the syntax `cut -c 25-` (i.e. use a minus sign instead of a plus sign) to remove the first 24 characters.

You're also searching for different patterns in your two examples, in case that's relevant.

Comment: oops! i am using the 'minus' sign - that was a typo in my post here