# Minimizing buffered pipe that delays loop processing in bash

Tags: bash, shell, loops, redirect, pipe

I have a loop that will be following a log file as it grows, searching for a pattern and reacting to it. The problem is that I am hitting a buffer somewhere that delays the loop from getting input, and I believe it's due to `tail -f` and piping the log to `grep`.

**Does not work**

```sh
while read l; do echo "l = |$l|"; done < <(tail -f $logfile | grep $pattern)
```

I have setup `$logfile` as a `fifo` and have to `cat realfile.log > $logfile` 3 or 4 times (realfile.log is ~2K lines), before a buffer seems to fill and the lines are processed *at once* through the loop.

If I remove the `grep $pattern` from the redirected stdin, the file is processed as expected.

**Does work**

```sh
while read l; do echo "l = |$l|"; done < <(tail -f $logfile)
```

**Also works**

```sh
while read l; do echo "l = |$l|"; done < <(tail $logfile | grep $pattern)
```

Is it that `tail` is not `fsync()'ing` the writes on `-f`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972370/how-do-you-pipe-input-through-grep-to-another-utility

Comment: lain, didn't see that in my search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the following:

> If I remove the `grep $pattern` from the redirected stdin, the file is
>   processed as expected.

`grep` buffers the output that causes the *delay*.  Use the `--line-buffered` option for `grep` to disable buffering.

Quoting from `man grep`:

```
   --line-buffered
          Use  line  buffering  on  output.   This can cause a performance
          penalty.
```

Comment: D'oh should have RTFM for grep, not tail!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding line buffering to grep :

```
... grep --line-buffered $pattern ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm accepting @devnull's since its a little more complete.